# EntityFrameworkCore.Jet for .NET 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, jet-ef-provider

[EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet) is .NET Standard 2.0 compatible. Is there a pure .NET 6 version of a similar Access Database EF driver/provider?

**[Update]**

**Clarification**: By *"pure .net 6.0 build"* I don't mean to have (developed) MS Access .mdb and .accdb files' C# drivers working without MS Access Runtime - I wanted  [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/Directory.Build.props](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet/blob/master/Directory.Build.props), which in current *master*-branch [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet) version (as on 18-SEP-22) has a section:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultNetCoreTargetFramework>net5.0</DefaultNetCoreTargetFramework>
    <WindowsOnlyNetCoreTargetFramework>net5.0-windows</WindowsOnlyNetCoreTargetFramework>
    <DefaultNetCoreLegacyTargetFramework>netcoreapp5.0</DefaultNetCoreLegacyTargetFramework>
    <DefaultNetStandardTargetFramework>netstandard2.1</DefaultNetStandardTargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to be presented as:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultNetCoreTargetFramework>net6.0</DefaultNetCoreTargetFramework>
    <WindowsOnlyNetCoreTargetFramework>net6.0</WindowsOnlyNetCoreTargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

or something like that with all the '*netstandardX*' and legacy dependencies removed, and all the necessary source code's edits and used packages dependencies' refactorings done.

Plus, for smooth transition from .NET Framework 4.7/4.8 to .NET 6.x of the legacy apps with MS Access backends, it would be helpful to have a special dedicated .NET Framework 4.8 build of [EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet).

Comment: I think that someone's working on it but there are some changes to interfaces so it's not a 5 minutes work. Probably is better if you check on github.

Comment: OK, I see there is [experimental .net6 version of EntityFrameworkCore.Jet](https://github.com/ChrisJollyAU/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet). I have tried to compile it. All the libraries' projects compile well, and some test projects do not. The current goal of this project is to refactor the code to make all the test projects to compile without errors and to run `Green`, or some of the test code is obsolete and has to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

The EF provider does not implement the full stack (all the EF providers works in this way).
For access to mdb and accdb files it uses Microsoft libraries that are not portable (do you mean this for pure .NET?).
Some years ago developers (we) spoke about using a portable library but we did not find a read/write library written in C#.
I don't know if now there is such library out there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have posted an update/clarification to my original post. Please comment if you have any plans on developing/upgrading of the `EntityFrameworkCore.Jet` codebase to make it a _pure .NET 6.0_ version (as I clarified in my update).